# Not able to create a smoother curve fit plot

Tags: r

How to smoothen the fit curve?

```
XY <- data.frame(cbind(Values = c(91.8, 95.3,   99.8,   123.3,  202.9,  619.8,  1214.2, 1519.1, 1509.2, 1523.3, 1595.2, 1625.1),
            Concn = c(1000, 300,    100,    30, 10, 3,  1,  0.3,    0.1,    0.03,   0.01,   0)))
nls.fit <- nls(Values ~ (ymax* Concn / (ec50 + Concn)) + Ns*XY$Concn + ymin, data=XY,
                   start=list(ymax=max(XY$Values), ymin = min(XY$Values), ec50 = 3, Ns = 0.2045514))
plot(XY$Values ~ XY$Concn , data = XY, col = 4, main = "XY Std curve", log = "x")
lines(XY$Concn, predict(nls.fit))
```

When I tried the following script, I get error msg.

```
SmoothX <- seq(min(XY$Values), max(XY$Values), length = 100)
lines(SmoothX, predict(nls.fit,SmoothX), col='red', lwd=2)
```

Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'SmoothX')

How to fix the error?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that XY is sorted in ascending order of `Concn` to ensure that when we use `lines` that each point is connected to the next sorted point and not to some other point.  Also be sure to remove `XY` from the formula since it is already specified in the `data` argument and will cause problems if present. Use the `plot` and `lines` argument, `subset`, to exclude 0 from the data used in `plot` and `lines` since they specify logarithmic scales.

```
o <- order(XY$Concn)
XY <- XY[o, ]

fo <- Values ~ (ymax* Concn / (ec50 + Concn)) + Ns * Concn + ymin
st <- list(ymax=max(XY$Values), ymin = min(XY$Values), ec50 = 3, Ns = 0.2045514)
nls.fit <- nls(fo, data = XY, start = st)

plot(Values ~ Concn, XY, subset = Concn > 0, col = 4, log = "x")
title(main = "XY Std curve")
lines(predict(nls.fit, new = list(Concn = Concn)) ~ Concn, XY, subset = Concn > 0) ##
```

Optionally, it could be made even smoother by replacing the `lines` statement (marked ## above) with the following 3 lines of code to provide a greater number of points equally spaced on a log scale.  Note that we remove the 0 point before taking logarithms.

```
logRange <- with(XY, log(range(Concn[Concn > 0])))
x <- exp(seq(logRange[1], logRange[2], length = 100))
lines(x, predict(nls.fit, new = list(Concn = x)))
```

Omitting the line marked ## and then running all the rest of the code above including the last 3 lines we get:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! I very much appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

First I think your new data to be used in the predictions should be using concentrations instead of values:

```
SmoothX <- seq(min(XY$Concn), max(XY$Concn), length = 100)
```

Additionally, look that SmoothX and predict(nls.fit,SmoothX) differ in length:

```
str(SmoothX)
```

num [1:100] 91.8 107.3 122.8 138.3 153.8 ...

```
str(predict(nls.fit,SmoothX))
```

num [1:12] 109.5 49 52.3 120.6 298.6 ...

But, if you include `list(Concn=SmoothX)` you will get a vector of 100 values as your new data vector length is.

```
 str(predict(nls.fit,list(Concn=SmoothX)))
```

num [1:100] 1714 324.7 175.5 119.6 91.8 ...

This works better but it still gives a warning message and a poorly ugly red line :c.

```
lines(SmoothX, predict(nls.fit,list(Concn=SmoothX)), col='red', lwd=2)
```

Warning message:
In (ymax * Concn/(ec50 + Concn)) + Ns * XY$Concn :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

[image: Plot produced]

Comment: Thank you for teaching step by step on how to get a vector of 100 values for plotting. This will be very useful to many of them like me out there..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use a formula in `nls()` without `XY$` in it:

```
nls.fit <- nls(Values ~ (ymax* Concn / (ec50 + Concn)) + 
                         Ns*Concn + ymin,
               data=XY,
               start=list(ymax=max(XY$Values), ymin = min(XY$Values),
                          ec50 = 3, Ns = 0.2045514))
```

Plot:

```
plot(Values ~ Concn , data = XY, col = 4, main = "XY Std curve",
     log = "x")
```

If you're going to plot on a log-X scale it will help to spread your prediction values evenly on the log scale. You also need the prediction data to be a data frame with the same variable name (`Conc`) as the predictor variable in your model:

```
SmoothX <- with(XY,
      data.frame(Concn=10^seq(min(log10(Concn[Concn>0])),
                              max(log10(Concn)), length = 100)))
pp <- predict(nls.fit,SmoothX)
lines(SmoothX$Concn, pp, col='red', lwd=2)


 plot(Values ~ Concn , data = XY, col = 4, main = "XY Std curve",
     log = "x")
SmoothX <- with(XY,
      data.frame(Concn=10^seq(min(log10(Concn[Concn>0])),
                              max(log10(Concn)), length = 100)))
pp <- predict(nls.fit,SmoothX)
lines(SmoothX$Concn, pp, col='red', lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I very much appreciate your guidance.  I like your answer as well as G. Grothendieck's answer equally. Since G. Grothendieck answer was the first answer, I selected it. Sorry!